# thunderbird's v45 "integrated calendar" (lightning) is missing?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

so, I updated thunderbird to v.45.

I read that from v.38 lightning would be integrated,to my surprise, there is no calendar anywhere to be reached from the menus, neither at preferences (it should be at preferences, a tab there).

I read lightning should be enabled when building thunderbird, therefore ubuntu's one was no lightning at all?

but, how to I get my calendar working again? compile from sources?!? :(

the other questions about it are too old related to thunderbird version.

btw, here is ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Lightning is available as add-on in Thunderbird under `Tools > Add-Ons` but I didn't try to install it this way as I don't need  Lightning. Try and check if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lightning package seems to still be available as a separate package. I am not sure, but the decision to not integrate it into the Thunderbird package could possibly be a conscious choice by the Ubuntu maintainers of the software. I'm not running 14.04 LTS "Trusty" anymore but I see the package on this 16.04 LTS "Xenial" system --

```
$ sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning
```

A search at packages.ubuntu.com shows the updated Lightning package IS available for Trusty.